# MVC 5 Login Timeout Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

In my MVC 5 application, users are timed out after 20 minutes and returned to the login page, even though I've set all my settings to be 600 minutes.  I am using forms authentication and have changed my web config to contain:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="600" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="600" />
```

My Account Controller, I've manually set the cookie to persistent:

```
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
        HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
```

EDIT:

I forgot to mention I have changed my IIS Settings, but to no avail.

[image]

How do I get it to respect my web.config timeout?

Comment: It might be the AppPool in IIS that is restarting after 20 minutes, which is automatically killing your sessions.

Comment: Sparrow - I had already changed that, I just updated with a picture

Comment: Leonard - I see that, so how do I over-ride it when creating the cookie?

Comment: @LéonardLaiter - the web.config timeout is used by `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`: the article you link refers to creating a ticket manually using the FormsAuthenticationTicket class, which is not the case here.  The configuration looks OK, though the session timeout has nothing to do with the FormsAuthentication timeout.  @JoeStellato  Are you sure you don't have any code in the application that logs the user out if a Session variable is no longer available (which can happen, as @Sparrow says, because of an AppPool recycle)?

Comment: @Joe I've searched all the code for FormsAuthentication.SignOut() and SignOut() but nothing comes up.  AppPool is set to never timeout as well.

Comment: @JoeStellato - adding logging to the Application_Start and Application_End event will confirm if the application is being recycled.  Otherwise I can only suggest cutting down to a minimal sample that reproduces the behavior, and perhaps examining the HTTP traffic with Fiddler or similar, and adding logging to other events such as Application_AuthenticateRequest.